# Flask not running application.py when using flask_socketio 0.0.0.0 refused to connect

Tags: flask, cloud9-ide, flask-socketio

When I start my Flask server in Cloud9, I usually get a message and URL that looks like this `Running on http://ide50-user.cs50.io:8080/`.

I'm now trying to run a Flask app that includes `flask_socketio`.

The original program text is below:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret"
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    pass
```

When I ran it with the debugger off, I got nothing.

When I turned the debugger on, I got the following:

```
(3015) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

When I followed the link, I got the following error message:

```
This site can’t be reached
0.0.0.0 refused to connect.
```

I tried appending the following, as suggested in other posts (not simultaneously, but first one and then the other), and got the same error:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host="ide50-user.cs50.io", port=8080, threaded=True)
    #app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, threaded=True)
```

What's going on, and how can I get this up and running?

Answer (score 0):

The `0.0.0.0` address is not an address that you connect to, it is used when you start the server to indicate that the server should listen on all the public IP addresses your system has.

You can connect to this server from the same machine using `http://localhost:8080` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. You can also connect to the server from any other machine in your network using the IP address assigned to the machine running the server.